# How to create BitLocker encrypted DVD disks?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption

I am planning to copy my personal data on CD/DVD disks for archival reasons. But I don't want anyone who has the disk to access my data without a password.

So how can I create CD/DVD disks that are  encrypted?

I am thinking of two methods.

1. Create VHD files > Put data in it > Encrypt it with BitLocker > Burn *.vhd file to DVD
2. Burn data to DVD > Encrypt the whole disk directly (if possible)

Any ideas on how should it be done? Is there some kind of risk (of error or corruption or, data loss)?

Any advice or information would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: The first method looks like it should work and corruption is always a threat to long-term storage of any kind, encryption probably won't make it much worse (that said, using some error-checking-and-correcting code may be a smart idea).

Comment: Actually it could easily make it worse as a simple corruption within the header, for most container formats, would make the whole content of the disc inaccessible rather than only certain bits. I'm not aware of a CD/DVD filesystem that is encrypted by default so you will probably have to rely on encrypting the data before writing it. As you said you could use a VHD, you could use a TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt container or you could use some encrypted tar/zip/other compression format.